# How to read a file with both decimal and hex/binary values in MATLAB

Tags: file, matlab, binary

Say you have a simple text file which contains many columns. Some columns are decimal values already. Some are hexadecimal. Those columns are known.

test.txt >>

```
1.4 1.9 21 0030 0D12
0.3 3.3 91 FFFF 1111
```

I want to read the first three columns as decimal, and read the last two columns as hex.

Can this be done easily?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can easily be done by [`textread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textread.html). For your example, just do:

```
[col1, col2, col3, col4, col5] = textread('myfile.txt', '%f %f %f %s %s');
```

This will read the decimal values normally, and treat the hexadecimal values as strings.

If you further wish to convert the strings into decimal values as well, use [`hex2dec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hex2dec.html) with [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html):

```
[col4, col5] = cellfun(@hex2dec, col4, col5);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fscanf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html). Are the hexadecimal values supposed to be all positive? If so, you may scan it like this:

```
fscanf(file_id,'%f %f %d %x %x')
```